# psql IS NOT NULL returns f

Tags: psql

I have a function, registration, which is supposed to add a row to a table under certain circumstances.  I've included a snippet of code.  If the select * returns a non-empty table row, I want to raise the exception and not add the row.  The example seems to show that rowt is not null, and yet  rowt IS NOT NULL returns f (and the exception is not raised).  I hope this is something minor I'm not seeing.

```
    select * into rowt from Email where email_email = eml;
    RAISE NOTICE '%, rowt IS NOT NULL:%',rowt, rowt IS NOT NULL;
    if rowt IS NOT NULL THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'email address, %, already registered.' , eml;
    END IF;

    NOTICE:  (7,,,), rowt IS NOT NULL:f
    registration 
    --------------
        21
    (1 row)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special variable `FOUND` to check if a row has been found and returned.

```sql
SELECT * INTO rowt FROM Email WEHERE email_email = eml;

IF FOUND THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'email address, %, already registered.' , eml;
END IF;
```